# How to get value of input attribute and background color of nearby div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have some div with `id = "ctl00_ContentPlace_dvColorsArea"` inside that div I have inputs of type text.

Under every input I have div element that contains another child div.

Here is example:

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlace_dvColorsArea">

    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlace$ctl00" type="text" legendlabel="Zone:  AGR" style="display: none;">
    <div class="sp-replacer sp-light sp-active">
            <div class="sp-preview">
                <div class="sp-preview-inner" style="background-color: rgb(235, 217, 190,0.12);"></div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlace$ctl00" type="text" legendlabel="Zone:  ZGY" style="display: none;">
    <div class="sp-replacer sp-light sp-active">
            <div class="sp-preview">
                <div class="sp-preview-inner" style="background-color: rgb(85, 45, 50);"></div>
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

At some point I need to get from every input attribute with name legendlabel his value and background-color of the child div
under the input element.

For example according to HTML above :

```
[{
    legendlabel:"Zone:  AGR"
    backgroundColor:rgb(235, 217, 190,0.12)
},
{
    legendlabel="Zone:  ZGY"
    backgroundColor:rgb(85, 45, 50)
}]
```

I know that using this row `$("#ctl00_ContentPlace_dvColorsArea :input").attr(legendlabel);`
I can get attribute value of every input.  But I need to get also a childs div background color.

Any idea how can I get from every input attribute with name legendlabel his value and background-color of the child div
under the input element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```js
var ele = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlace_dvColorsArea').getElementsByTagName("input");
var output = [...ele].map((val, i)=> {
  return {
   legendlabel: val.getAttribute("legendlabel"),
   backgroundColor: $(val).next().find('.sp-preview-inner').css('background-color')
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlace_dvColorsArea">

    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlace$ctl00" type="text" legendlabel="Zone:  AGR" style="display: none;">
    <div class="sp-replacer sp-light sp-active">
            <div class="sp-preview">
                <div class="sp-preview-inner" style="background-color: rgb(235, 217, 190,0.12);"></div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlace$ctl00" type="text" legendlabel="Zone:  ZGY" style="display: none;">
    <div class="sp-replacer sp-light sp-active">
            <div class="sp-preview">
                <div class="sp-preview-inner" style="background-color: rgb(85, 45, 50);"></div>
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @Michael `...` is called the spread operator it s used to spread the values of an iterable value inside another so that `map` can work

Comment: Hi I just noticed that you have mistake. I need all elements that inside div with id="ctl00_ContentPlace_dvColorsArea".Can you please update code?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlace_dvColorsArea :input').each(function (index, value) { 
 var label =  $(value).attr("legendlabel");
 var color = $(value).next().find(".sp-preview-inner").css("background-color");
 console.log(label);
 console.log(color);
});
```